# Use Canon AE-1 lenses on a Sony Alpha a6000

Tags: canon, sony, sony-alpha

I have found that my father had an old Canon AE-1 film camera, and I'm about to buy a Sony Alpha a6000 camera. The old AE-1 camera has a good 80mm lens that I'd love to use on my Sony camera, even if all the focus and zooming is manual (I love manual). Is there a chance to have an adapter to use that lens on the Sony.

Cheers!

Comment: Quick googling reveals: https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/1150786-REG/fotodiox_fd_nex_p_pro_lens_mount_adapter.html

Comment: How do you know that the old AE-1 use FD Lens?

Comment: @JorgeRevuelta Do your homework, see the [wikipedia entry on the AE-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canon_AE-1) (see side bar and "Features" section).

Comment: The mount type may even be listed on the lens itself. As in the product photo juhist linked...

Comment: Yah, tried to get the mount type in the lens without luck

Comment: The Canon AE-1 does use Canon FD lens's, it will also except the older FL lens's. It should say on the lens. It will say on the front of the lens,  "CANON LENS FD 80-200mm F 4"  https://mir.com.my/rb/photography/companies/canon/fdresources/fdlenses/fdzooms/80200.htm#80-200mmL

Comment: An amazon search for "canon nex" will yield plenty of both EF and FD mount adapters, which should make a good starting point for research regarding which canon mounts are there....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Sony Alpha a6000 uses the Sony E-mount. There are many adapters available that will allow you to use a Canon FD lens from a Canon AE-1 on your Sony Alpha a6000 camera.

[FD to Sony E-mount adapters at Amazon.com](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=Canon%20FD%20to%20sony%20e-mount%20adapter&s=price-asc-rank&qid=1552776766&ref=sr_st_price-asc-rank)